# как убрать колонку с инструментами справа в outlook 2013?

Tags: outlook

[image: как убрать колонку с инструментами справа в outlook 2013?]

Здравствуйте,
Помогите пожалуйста изменить интерфейс Outlook. Убрать вертикальную панель с инструментами справа и сделать возможность удалять письма кликая на само письмо.

Comment: @Духсообщества, иди в баню) Нашёл, что апать.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы убрать боковую панель, необходимо переключить режим сенсорного управления или мыши в режим мыши. Режим сенсорного управления находится вверху, на панели быстрого доступа.

Comment: Большоке спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо, помогли! Сначала расстроился, что столько места пропадает.